# MATCH() AGAINST() & Fulltext index: Possible to have "keywords" field?

Tags: sql, mysql, full-text-search

I'm using MATCH() AGAINST() with a fulltext index and I was wondering how I could setup a "keywords" data field.

So let's say I have a a fulltext index on the "title" column, which for example might have a row with the value of "AC/DC".. I want to have a field to enter additional keywords like "ACDC" "AC DC" and "AC-DC"

Ideally I'd like to specify these keywords in comma-delimited text form, like this:

```
Title: "AC/DC"
Keywords: "ACDC, AC DC, AC-DC"
```

Any idea how I might accomplish this from a database perspective?

Let me know if you need any clarification!

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please - ***no*** comma separated values.  Store the keyword info in a separate table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`keywords`;
CREATE TABLE  `example`.`keywords` (
  `title` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_idx` (`title`,`keyword`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```